# SQL Server map payments to products

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have shopping carts that might have included products and payments.

Since these payments will be made to the carts, there will be no relation between the products and the payments except that they are in the same cart.

There are cases that these products will be invoiced individually even though they are in the same cart.

To create the invoices for the products we need the payment details, so we have to map the products to the payments.

These are our tables:

```
create table Products 
(
     ItemId int primary key, 
     CartId int not null, 
     ItemAmount smallmoney not null 
)

create table Payments 
(
     PaymentId int primary key, 
     CartId int not null, 
     PaymentAmount smallmoney not null 
)

create table MappedTable 
(
     ItemId int not null, 
     PaymentId int not null, 
     Amount smallmoney not null 
)

INSERT INTO Products (ItemId, CartId, ItemAmount) 
VALUES  (1, 1, 143.49), (2, 1, 143.49), (3, 1, 143.49),  (4, 2, 50.00), (5, 3, 75.00), (6, 3, 75.00) 

INSERT INTO Payments (PaymentId, CartId, PaymentAmount) 
VALUES  (1, 1, 376.47), (2, 1, 54.00), (3, 2, 60.00), (4, 3, 140.00)

--select * from Products
--select * from Payments
--DROP TABLE Products
--DROP TABLE Payments
--DROP TABLE MappedTable
```

**Products**

```
ItemId | CartId | ItemAmount
------ | ------ | ----------
     1 |      1 |     143.49
     2 |      1 |     143.49
     3 |      1 |     143.49
     4 |      2 |      50.00
     5 |      3 |      75.00
     6 |      3 |      75.00
```

**Payments**

```
PaymentId | CartId | PaymentAmount
--------- | ------ | -------------
        1 |      1 |        376.47
        2 |      1 |         54.00
        3 |      2 |         60.00
        4 |      3 |        140.00
```

The order of the products and the payments may differ.

We need the output to look like this:

**MappingTable**

```
ItemId | PaymentId | MappedAmount
------ | --------- | ------------
     1 |         1 |     143.49
     2 |         1 |     143.49
     3 |         1 |      89.49
     3 |         2 |      54.00
     4 |         3 |      50.00 (Remaining 10.00 from Payment 3 will be ignored)
     5 |         4 |      75.00
     6 |         4 |      65.00 (Missing 10.00 from Payment 4 will be ignored)
```

- Cart 1: Sum of payments = sum of product costs
- Cart 2: Sum of payments > sum of product costs. Only take the total product cost. Ignore the remaining 10.00
- Cart 3: Sum of payments < sum of product costs. Take all the payments, ignore the fact that the payment is 10.00 short.

I thought that a query like the one below may solve the problem, but no luck.

```
insert into MappedTable
    select 
        prd.ItemId, pay.PaymentId, 
        (Case 
            when prd.ItemAmount - isnull((select sum(m.Amount) 
                                          from MappedTable m 
                                          where m.ItemId = prd.ItemId), 0) <= pay.PaymentAmount - isnull((select sum(m.Amount) from MappedTable m where m.PaymentId = pay.PaymentId), 0) 
               then prd.ItemAmount - isnull((select sum(m.Amount) from MappedTable m where m.ItemId = prd.ItemId), 0)
            else pay.PaymentAmount - isnull((select sum(m.Amount) from MappedTable m where m.PaymentId = pay.PaymentId), 0)                 
        end)
    from 
        Products prd 
    inner join 
        Payments pay on pay.CartId = prd.CartId
    where 
        prd.ItemAmount > isnull((select sum(m.Amount) from MappedTable m where m.ItemId = prd.ItemId), 0)
        and pay.PaymentAmount > isnull((select sum(m.Amount) from MappedTable m where m.PaymentId = pay.PaymentId), 0)
```

I've read about CTE (Common Table Expressions) and set-based approaches but I couldn't handle the issue.

So is this possible without using a cursor or a while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, this kind of task is referred to as a "[knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)", which is known to have no solution more efficient than brute forcing all possible combinations. In your case, however, you have additional conditions, namely ordered sets of both items and payments, so it is actually solvable using "overlapping intervals" technique.

The idea is to generate ranges of items and payments (1 pair of ranges per cart) and then look which payments overlap with which items, sequentially.

For any item-payment combination, there are 3 possible scenarios:

1. Payment covers the beginning of the item range (possibly completely covering the item);
2. Payment is completely inside the item;
3. Payment covers the end of item, thus "closing" it.

So, all that is needed is, for every item, find all suitable payments that match the aforementioned criteria, and order them by their identifiers. Here is a query that does it:

```
with cte as (
    -- Project payment ranges, per cart
    select pm.*, sum(pm.PaymentAmount) over(partition by pm.CartId order by pm.PaymentId) as [RT]
    from @Payments pm
)
select q.ItemId, q.PaymentId,
  -- Calculating the amount from payment that goes for this item
    case q.Match
        when 1 then q.PaymentRT - (q.ItemRT - q.ItemAmount)
        when 2 then q.PaymentAmount
        when 3 then case
            -- Single payment spans over several items
            when q.PaymentRT >= q.ItemRT and q.PaymentRT - q.PaymentAmount <= q.ItemRT - q.ItemAmount then q.ItemAmount
            -- Payment is smaller than item
            else q.ItemRT - (q.PaymentRT - q.PaymentAmount)
        end
    end as [Amount]
  --, q.*
from (
    select
        sq.ItemId, pm.PaymentId, sq.ItemAmount, sq.RT as [ItemRT],
        pm.PaymentAmount, pm.RT as [PaymentRT],
        row_number() over(partition by sq.CartId, sq.ItemId, pm.PaymentId order by pm.RT) as [RN],
        pm.Match
        --, sq.CartId
    from (
        select pr.*, sum(pr.ItemAmount) over(partition by pr.CartId order by pr.ItemId) as [RT]
        from @Products pr
    ) sq
        outer apply (
            -- First payment to partially cover this item
            select top (1) c.*, 1 as [Match] from cte c where c.CartId = sq.CartId
                and c.RT > sq.RT - sq.ItemAmount and c.RT < sq.RT
            order by sq.RT
            union all
            -- Any payments that cover this item only
            select c.*, 2 as [Match] from cte c where c.CartId = sq.CartId
                and c.RT - c.PaymentAmount > sq.RT - sq.ItemAmount
                and c.RT < sq.RT
            union all
            -- Last payment that covers this item
            select top (1) c.*, 3 as [Match] from cte c where c.CartId = sq.CartId
                and c.RT >= sq.RT
            order by sq.RT
        ) pm
    ) q
where q.RN = 1;
```

The `outer apply` section is where I get payments related to each item. The only problem is, if a payment covers an item in its entirety, it will be listed several times. In order to remove these duplicates, I have ordered matches using `row_number()` and added an additional wrapping level - subquery with the `q` alias - where I cut off any duplicated rows by filtering the row number value.

P.S. If your SQL Server version is prior to 2012, you will need to calculate running totals using one of many approaches available on the Internet, because `sum() over(order by ...)` is only available on 2012 and later versions.

Comment: I added a product and a payment to Cart3  - INSERT INTO Products values (7, 3, 65.00); INSERT INTO Payments values (5, 3, 75.00) - _it miscalculated the cart_

Comment: Also there are cases that payments and products can be added to the cart, I need to map them too without changing existing mappings.

Comment: @gokhanpolat, updated the query, amount calculation reworked.

Comment: yeah it works, thanks, great solution that if you do mapping process at one time. Do you have any idea about my second comment?

Comment: Existing mapping records can be excluded via `left join MappingTable mt on ... where mt.ItemId is null`, or an equivalent `not exists (...)` clause. It might be a bit tricky to take partially covered items, however.

Comment: I did it a while ago and I was going to post the last query but you wrote first. Thank you very much again. I will update the post very soon.